# Capturando as teclas pressionadas pelo usuário em Python no Linux

Tags: python, linux

```
import pyHook
import pythoncom

def tecla_pressionada(evento):
   # print("Alguma tecla pressionada")
    print (chr(evento.Ascii))

hook = pyHook.HookManager()
hook.KeyDown = tecla_pressionada #sem ()
hook.HookKeyboard()

pythoncom.PumpMessages() #cria loop infinito e espera mensagens do SO
```

O código acima funciona com a biblioteca `pyHook` para Windows.

Como fazer um código semelhante em Python para Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o [`pyxhook`](https://github.com/JeffHoogland/pyxhook):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pyxhook

def OnKeyPress(event):
    print (event.Key)

    # Pressione <space> para terminar o script
    if event.Ascii == 32:
        exit(0)

hm = pyxhook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyPress

hm.HookKeyboard()

hm.start()
```

Para usar o `pyxhook` faça o seguinte:

1. Copie o código [**dessa página**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JeffHoogland/pyxhook/master/pyxhook.py) e salve o arquivo como `pyxhook.py` na mesma pasta do teu *script*.
2. Se você não tiver instalado o [Xlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xlib) instale:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python-xlib
   ```

Comment: como instalar o pyxhook?

Comment: @EdS Atualizei a resposta, veja.

Comment: Obrigado, @zekk.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do [stderr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/6454/stderr), descobri por acaso o seguinte:

Ao executar o código acima e pressionar qualquer tecla, será gerado uma *Key*, exemplo (imagem):

[image: Imagem]

Apenas alterei o código, adicionando a *Key* gerada, ficando da seguinte forma:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pyxhook

def OnKeyPress(event):
    print (event.Key)

# Pressione <Ctrl> para terminar o script
if event.Key == "Control_L":
    exit(0)

hm = pyxhook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyPress

hm.HookKeyboard()
hm.start()
```

Caso queira verificar se a letra "b" foi pressionada, basta adicionar a *Key* **bb**, e assim por diante.