# Como capturar eventos no Python?

Tags: python

Eu gostaria de capturar as teclas clicadas pelo usuário através do IronPython. Eu entendo um pouco de C#, mas não estou entendendo como faria isso no Python.

**Código:**

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')
from System.Windows.Forms import KeyEventArgs, Form, Application, Button

class App(Form):
    def __init__(self):

        self.KeyUp = self.TeclaClicada #Não sei como faria, aqui está o erro.
        self.Text = "Capturar tecla"

    def TeclaClicada(self, key):
        print(key)

form = App()
Application.Run(form)
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Capturando as teclas pressionadas pelo usuário em Python no Linux](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145588/capturando-as-teclas-pressionadas-pelo-usu%c3%a1rio-em-python-no-linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.KeyUp += self.TeclaClicada
```

Ou `self.KeyDown` ou `self.KeyPress`... depende da tecla que você quer capturar, algumas vão pra um evento, outras pra outro...

A sua função `TeclaClicada` tem que ter essa assinatura:

```
def TeclaClicada(self, e, args):
    key = e.KeyChar
    if key == ...:
        ...
```